# Meteor function executed twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor, velocity.js

I am using ***velocity.js*** for one of my apps. I have the following code:

```
Template.jumbotron.events({

      'mouseleave .css-logo-image':function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        $(".meteor_head").velocity({
          translateY: [ 0, 50 ]
        });
      },

      'mouseenter .css-logo-image':function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        console.log("translate out");
        $('.meteor_head').velocity({
        /* Two-item array format. */
        translateY: [ 50, 0 ]
    });
        return false;
      },
    })
```

But the first time I hover over the element and then leave both functions happens twice. As you can see, I tried:

```
event.preventDefault; event.stopPropagination; return false;
```

But it does not help. It is interesting that when I try:

```
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".meteor_head").velocity({
      translateY: "-25px"
    });
```

It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`preventDefault` is a function so it should be `preventDefault()`.

Comment: I fixed this. Still executed twice.

Comment: Suggest you isolate the issue by replacing  $(".meteor_head") with a simple console log to make sure velocity does not impact the situation. Good luck.